# URL rewrite to specific site on in the same IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Having a problem with IIS to redirect URL to specific site.

Setup in IIS :

servername:  webserver1

Sites in webserver1:

- Default Site   :https port 443
- site2          :https port 2222
- site3          :https port 3333

I created A host DNS record named:  site2  that poiting to  webserver1

Problem+want to achieve:

when I type in URL:  https://site2  I want to reach the site2 that on port 2222
The problem is when I type now site2  I reach to the default web site on port 443 ranther than site2.   Of course If I type:  https://site2:2222 everything works fine.

How can I redirect so I'll only have to type  site2  and it will start the site2 over port 2222 ?
[image: IIS Setup]
[image: URL Flow]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "I created A host DNS record named: site2 that poiting to webserver1." That's rare. Are you doing it in an internal network?

Comment: Yes.  The site for internal users only.  and it the web server has only 1 IP

Comment: What is the IIS version? For 8+ you don't need such hack. And also for internal usage, even on IIS 7.x, you can request a SAN certificate to host multiple HTTPS sites on a single IP at port 443. There is no need to go the complex way.

Comment: IIS 8,  and don't understand understand why SAN would help me if you can host only 1 site per port.  you not allowed to host multiple sites on the same port... this is sort of what I try resolve.

Comment: For IIS 8 you don't need SAN at all, but SNI. I documented the background you should be aware of https://www.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background . Remove your current site bindings, and instead utilize SNI to recreate them to share port 443. It is super easy to configure, and powerful enough to help you.

Comment: Sorry Lex, I'm looking for native option and not 3rd party solution. don't know why my request is seem complex as it should be simple.  I hit the default site over 443 and it will redirect me to different site depending on the URL  I'm using.. should be simple.

Comment: With the background information, you can configure SNI with or without Jexus Manager. Microsoft has similar documentation, which you can find from Google searches.

Comment: Also about "simple", SNI is the simplest and in the meantime giving you the best performance (as it removes all the extra cost).